# ethereumjs-tx : sign transaction using unlocked account

Tags: transactions, signature, ethereumjs-tx

Web3js has the following method :

```
web3.eth.signTransaction(transactionObject, address [, callback])
```

to sign a transaction using an unlocked account.

Can we sign a transaction in a similar way, without explicitly providing the private key, with ethereumjs-tx ?

Comment: I believe that the answer is no. Use web3.js if you have to rely on an unlocked account, but preferably - don't use an unlocked account. Sign the transaction before you send it to the node.

Comment: @clement Why do you want to use ethereumjs-tx instead of signTransaction? Which functionality of ethereumjs-tx is missing?

Comment: @Ismael My objective is to sign a transaction on the client side, then send the raw transaction object to a backend server, and finally broadcast it from the back. As I set my web3 provider in my backend, I therefore don't want to use web3js in my frontend but a lower-level library instead.

Comment: @clement How will you manage the private key on the client side? Will you use MetaMask or you will handle it yourself?

Comment: @Ismael I will use Metamask.

Comment: @clement Then why you want to use ethereumjs-tx. Metamask already provides web3.eth.sendTransaction. It will sign and send it without the need of a backend.

Comment: @Ismael The backend is part of the architecture (for special reasons). I don't want to broadcast the transactions from the client side.

Comment: @clement Does web3.eth.signTransaction work with metamask?